# prove thatt $\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{{(x+y)}^2}\ge 9/4$

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

> prove that $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{{(x+y)}^2}\ge 9/4$$ where $x,y,z$ are positives such that $xy+yz+xz=1$

By Holder;$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{{(x+y)}^2} \right){\left(\sum yz+zx \right)}^2\ge {\sum \left(z^{2/3} \right)}^{3}$$.

Hence it suffices to prove $$\sum {\left(z^{2/3} \right)}^{3}\ge 3^{2/3}$$ which is falsse.

I was able to get a weaker bound.since $xy+yz+zx=1$ we have $x^2+y^2\le 2$. By C-S and $x^2+y^2<2$
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{{(x+y)}^2}\ge \frac{1}{2}\sum \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}>3/4$$

I am interested on a solution using standard inequalities (C-S AM-GM,chebyshov etc) rather than fully expanding and using uvw/pqr/schur.

Comment: See [this thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h255362p1394793) on AoPS, which does use uvw but is still quite elegant. Found using Approach0.

Comment: C-S is weak in direct form I think; well what is the source of this problem?

Comment: @BookOfFlames It's Iran TST 96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\geq\frac{9}{4(xy+xz+yz)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}-\frac{3}{4(xy+xz+yz)}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{4xz+4yz-2xy-3x^2-3y^2}{(x+y)^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(z-x)(3x+y)-(y-z)(3y+x)}{(x+y)^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)\left(\frac{3y+z}{(y+z)^2}-\frac{3x+z}{(x+z)^2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(3xy+xz+yz-z^2)(x+y)^2\geq0.$$
Now, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(3xy+xz+yz-z^2)(x+y)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(xz+yz-z^2)(x+y)^2\geq$$
$$\geq(x-z)^2y(x+z-y)(x+z)^2+(y-z)^2x(y+z-x)(y+z)^2\geq$$
$$\geq(y-z)^2y(x-y)(x+z)^2+(y-z)^2x(y-x)(y+z)^2=$$
$$=(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(xy-z^2)\geq0.$$

Comment: wow! but how did you even comeup with such an idea?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore this is the SOS method.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution by Vo Quoc Ba Can.

Need to prove:
$$(xy+yz+zx)\left(\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+z)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}\right)\geqq \frac{9}{4}$$
Wlog, assume $x\geq y \geq z,$ we have the following lemma:
$$\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\geqq \frac{1}{4xy}+\frac{2}{(x+z)(y+z)}\quad \quad(1)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \left(\frac{1}{x+z}-\frac{1}{y+z}\right)^2\geqq \frac{(x-y)^2}{4xy(x+y)^2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 4xy(x+y)^2 \geqq (x+z)^2(y+z)^2$$
Since $x\geqq y \geqq z \therefore 4xy\geqq 4y^2\geqq (y+z)^2;(x+y)^2 \geqq (x+z)^2.$

So $(1)$ is true, need to prove:
$$(xy+yz+zx)\left(\frac{1}{4xy}+\frac{2}{(x+z)(y+z)}\right)\geqq\frac{9}{4}$$
But it's $$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\geq 8xyz,$$
which is true by AM-GM.

Comment: Do you know Chinese? I read your blog just now, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @TobyMak I know a little, but I can't write it well.